# How to use INDEX and MATCH to based to cells?

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match

I have two sheets of data in excel. I want to combine cells to bring the second cell value. Here is an example:

[image]

when I enter combining columns name and list must get value form V1 and V2.like this:

[image]

Comment: Search for match with multiple criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the time to type your data, so this is a rare case of a non-tested formula and may need some tweaking.

For the V1 result: (top screenshot starts in Sheet1 column A, bottom screenshot in Sheet2, column A). This formula goes into cell B2 in Sheet 2:

```
=Index( Sheet1!$E$2:$E$100, MATCH(Sheet2!a2,INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100&" | "&Sheet1!$D$1:$D$100,0),0))
```

Adjust the first index range from column E to F for the V2 result in C2.

Copy down.

Don't use that approach with whole columns. It will be slow. Use ranges with defined rows.

Of course, if the codes in Sheet1 column A are unique, you don't need to combine them with the value in column D and can look up only the first three characters, like this for V1 (use 6 for V2)

```
=vlookup(Left(Sheet2!A2,3),Sheet1!$A:$F,5,0)
```

Comment: Is it possible to match the second part of the cells? And ignore the first part of the cells. E.g. if I write: bdl | bajau, Indon list must value v1 and v1. If I just write bajau, Indon list must get V1 and V1  too.

Comment: I answered your question as you asked. Why did you unmark the answer? That was not polite. If you have another question, please ask a new question.

Comment: I marked it again. If you know how to match this formula with the second part of cells please let me do this. I have been stacking for a long time.